# Google sheets MM-DD-YYYY to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: google-sheets, date

I downloaded CSV data from my Etsy shop to calculate taxes. I'd like to have the date "copied" properly.

The CSV date I get from Etsy is formatted as "02/09/16"

This is "2 September 2016" in Dutch but "September 2 2016" in English.

I cannot seem to find a way to change this to the correct date. When changing language / time and locale settings, Google Sheets always makes sure it's exactly wrong. Setting everything to US or AUS returns the date as a Dutch date, setting everything to Dutch returns an English date!

I was thinking, I could extract the 2 numbers before the first dash "02", which is the month, and use `=vlookup()` to look up the month from a data sheet and paste this into a correct date. It seems to be a silly workaround but I can't seem to change the date properly.

```
        Col.A    Col.B
Row. 1)    01    January
Row. 2)    02    February
```

Lookup 01 and return B1. And so on…

Any ideas? I'm not exactly an Excel / spreadsheets guru.

Comment: _This is "2 September 2016" in Dutch but "September 2 2016" in English_ ... is confusing, I think you meant it's "February 9, 2016" in English.

Answer (score 5):

So you have something formatted mm/dd/yy, but your local format is dd/mm/yy. To recover the dates, you need

1. Format the imported dates as plain text. Suppose these are in column A
2. In column B, reconstruct the date in a less ambiguous format using `regexreplace`, and then use `datevalue` to turn it into a date. The column B should be formatted as a date.

The formula for B column is

```
=datevalue(regexreplace(A2, "(\d+)/(\d+)/\d*(\d{2})", "20$3-$1-$2"))
```

This replaces either 02/09/16 or 02/09/2016 by 2016-02-09, which is a date conforming to ISO 8601 standard, so it will be understood as 9th of February regardless of the local setting.

(If the date you're starting with is 2/9/16, then the converted form is 2016-2-9 which is not exactly ISO, but `datevalue` handles it the same way.)

#### Other separators

If some dates have hyphens `-` instead of slashes `/`, you can process them with the following regex:

```
=datevalue(regexreplace(A2, "(\d+)[-/](\d+)[-/]\d*(\d{2})", "20$3-$1-$2"))
```

Here, the character group `[-/]` means one character from those listed.

#### 20th century problems

The above assumes the dates refer to 21st  century. More work would be needed to also handle 02/09/98. For example: after doing the above, create one more column with

```
=if(year(B2)>2050, date(year(B2)-100, month(B2), day(B2)), B2)
```

This subtracts 100 years from the date if it's past 2050.

Answer (score 0):

To switch order of day and month regardless whether in Text or Date format:

```
=--join("/",index(split(A1,"/"),2),index(split(A1,"/"),1),right(A1,2))
```

[JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
[SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
[RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087)

If you know which 'direction' you need then whichever of the following suits would be shorter:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yy")
=--TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yy")
```

Again whether A1 is Text or Date format.

[TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)